# How to determine the three-point coordinates of a vector arrow

Tags: python, vector, pygame, coordinates, draw

i want to draw a vector whenever i drag the object which is a ball. I have drawn a segment, the remaining thing is to draw an arrow indicating the direction of the vector. But I can't determine the three-point coordinates to draw the correct direction the arrow is pointing. please help me. Thank you

```
try:
    import pygame,ctypes
    import pygame.draw as dr
    from math import *
    pygame.init()

    def interaction(xM,yM,x,y):
        if x<=xM and xM<=x+(10*sqrt(12)) and xM!=x:
            if y<=yM and yM<=y+(10*sqrt(2)) and yM!=y:
                return True
            else:return False
        else:return False

    def angle(x,y):
        if x>0:a=80
        else:a=-80
        return degrees(acos((x*a)/(abs(a)*vec_magnitude(x,y))))
    def vec_magnitude(x,y):
        return abs(sqrt((x**2)+(y**2)))
    length=1380
    width=720
    display=pygame.display.set_mode((length,width))
    #mau
    white=(255,255,255)
    black=(0,0,0)
    green=(0, 153, 51)
    red=(204, 0, 0)
    blue=(0, 51, 204)
    yellow=(255, 204, 0)
    xO,yO=80,620
    x,y=xO,yO-10
    running=True
    acceleration=bool(False)
    while running:
        display.fill(black)
        #vat nem
        da_ball=dr.circle(display,green,(x,y),10)
        pos=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        #print(pos)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:running=False
            #gia toc bong
            if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and interaction(pos[0],pos[1],x-(5*sqrt(2)),y-(5*sqrt(2))):
                acceleration=True
            elif event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:acceleration=False
        if acceleration:
            dr.line(display,yellow,(x,y),(pos[0],pos[1]),3)
            alp=angle(pos[0]-x,pos[1]-y)
            dx=8*sin(alp)
            dy=8*cos(alp)
            #Draw Vector Here
            if pos[0]>x and pos[1]<=y:
                dr.polygon(display,yellow,((pos[0]-dx,pos[1]-dy),(pos[0]+dx,pos[1]+dy),(pos[0]+dy,pos[1]-dx))) 
        pygame.display.update
    pygame.quit()
except Exception as e:
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0,str(e),"ErrorBox",16)
```

Comment: Don't put **everything** inside a try

Answer (score -1):

I noticed a couple of issues in your code:

The `pygame.display.update` function is missing parentheses. It should be `pygame.display.update()`.

You need to handle the case when `pos[0] <= x` in your angle calculation to avoid division by zero. You can set `a` to 0 in this case.

Comment: thanks but my arrow keep spinning when i drag

Comment: It may be because the angle (alp) you are using to calculate the arrow's direction is not being updated correctly. The issue might be that you are using the angle between the mouse position and the ball's position, which can cause the arrow to spin.
A more reliable approach would be to calculate the angle based on the change in mouse position (dx, dy).